# Force time series to drop the date part and keep only the time one

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

Mathematica's `TimeSeries` takes as an input the values and the time.
If I have a `TimeObject` with timestamps (without the date, only time (hour, minute, second) and I actually give this as an input to the `TimeSeries` I get a as a time part a full object with date (current date automatically assigned) and the input time that I gave.

Is there any way to force and not let take the date?
I give TimeObject[{10, 49, 32.599}, "Instant"]
It's returning DateObject[{2023, 2, 8, 10, 49, 32.599}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 2.]

I need this because later on I am using some `TimeSeriesWindow` manipulations. Maybe there is something and I am just not aware ?

tldr: I want to get rid of the 08 Feb 2023, inside the `TimeSeries` creation (I already give input time object not date object, so it's kinda weird).
[image]

Any suggestions ?!
Thanks

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMtaV.png). Could you include the output of `$Version` to your post? It seems version-related.

Comment: 13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)

Comment: It might seem weird but to my eyes supporting `TimeObject` in time series is problematic, shifting them could result in rotation and rearranging entries. As for 13.2, Mathematica adds a second from 1900-1-1 for each entry with `TimeObject` which is hard to follow. One solution is to pick a day like (1900-1-1) and convert all your `TimeObjects` to `DateObject`, so you make sure all dates fall in one day (keep in mind shifting too much is still problematic).